# ASP.net MVC Global Filtering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

This is sort of a broad question, but one I am curious about.

What are some examples of uses for MVC Global filters? I.E.

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new CustomFilterAttribute());
    }
```

I have seen many examples of stopwatches which while perfectly legitimate, lacks much real use.

I have also seen a few logging examples which is good, but I was wondering if anyone has any other thoughts on what to implement them for, or places you have used them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly in my opinion is security. You can have security applied to everything by default using a global action filter.

Global injecting of content - html or headers for example.

Comment: Would you do that with the Response.Write() ?

Comment: if writing raw html, then yes. otherwise for headers you would use filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers